# Rails respond_to? method in IF ... AND statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I am fetching list of users from our LDAP server:

```
filter_person = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq("objectClass", "person")
treebase = "ou=people,dc=rocketfuel,dc=com"
ldap.search(:base => treebase, :filter => filter_person, :scope => Net::LDAP::SearchScope_SingleLevel, :attributes => ['uid', 'sshpublickey']) do |entry|
  if users_uids.include?(entry.uid[0].to_s)
    p entry.uid[0].to_s
  end
 end
```

This code fails with the exception:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `uid' for #<Net::LDAP::Entry:0x00000000074bf558>
```

Which is expected (some of the users does not have UID). But what is not 100% clear for me why it is working if I change the `if` statement to:

```
if entry.respond_to?(:uid) and users_uids.include?(entry.uid[0].to_s)
  p entry.uid[0].to_s
end
```

I would expect it to through the same error (as `if ... and` statements calculates at the same time) **but it actually works well**.

Why doesn't `entry.uid[0]` raise the same exception when I add the `entry.respond_to?(:uid)` to the same conditional expression?

Comment: First and foremost, [don't use `and`](https://rubystyle.guide/#and-or-flow), use `&&`. They are not the same and `and` should be avoided. Secondly, regarding the closure of your question: Are you confused why `entry.respond_to?(:uid)` does not raise an exception, or why everything after the `and` (`users_uuis.include?entry.uid[0].to_s)` does not raise an exception, when preceded by the `respond_to?` call? These are different questions, telling us what part of this you don't understand allows us to answer the question you're actually asking.

Comment: I was interested why the second part "why everything after the and `(users_uids.include?entry.uid[0].to_s)` does not raise an exception" but I think I got my answer below. And thankd for `and` vs `&&` comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`And` operation does not execute both sides in all cases

In this example first, it will calculate the left side and only if the result is different than `false` or `nil` it continue to calculate the right part.

So if `entry.respond_to?(:uid)` evaluates to `nil`, the right part `users_uids.include?(entry.uid[0].to_s)` skipped.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `entry.uid` raises an exception when `uid` is not defined on `entry`. `entry.respond_to?(:uid)` returns falsely when there is no `uid` method defined on `entry`.

That means it works because the condition

```
if entry.respond_to?(:uid) and users_uids.include?(entry.uid[0].to_s)
```

evaluates to `false` in the first condition and the second condition is not checked anymore, because it would not change the result.

This is a feature is called [Short-Circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and it's present in most languages.